# Changing image addresses to https

Tags: bug, status-norepro, images

Why after changing http to https in an image, the image disappears:

[See this post's comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146810/62511)

Comment: This is the link to the image: https://i.imgur.com/PxBo1MWl.jpg; it works fine on my viewer (Chrome).

Comment: yes but in the post when edited, it was not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can access the image both using http and https:

HTTP:

[image: image via http]

And HTTPS‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌:

[image: image via https]

Comment: seems woking. But in that post it didn't both for me and another user. I'm not sure what was going on!

Comment: btw, In my location some http pic don't work. This is what I see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AM54b.jpg. This is why I prefer https pics. But, now it seems there's nothing wrong with https pics in posts.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus - that means that there is a problem on your end (browser, ISP or such), that doesn't make it a bug on our side.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your site. The problem is blocking regulations in some countries. Some http pictures are blocked for me.